# How to convert A string that represents an integer to unsigned byte array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, byte, unsigned

Basically, what I want is to convert a string like `"123456"` to unsigned byte array: `[1, 226, 64]`. However, I look everywhere and what I found is to get the 2's complements (signed) byte array `[1, -30, 64]`:

```
byte[] array = new BigInteger("123456").toByteArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[1, -30, 64]
```

So, how can it be done in Java? I want the output to be:

```
[1, 226, 64]
```

**EDIT:** I know that byte can hold only up to 127, so instead of byte array I need it to be int array.

Comment: There is no `unsigned byte` type in Java, therefore you'll have to convert it into `signed short/int` array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java has no unsigned types, so you'll have to store the values in an int array.

```
byte[] array = new BigInteger("123456").toByteArray(); 
int[] unsigned_array = new int[array.length]; 
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
    unsigned_array[i] = array[i] >= 0 ? array[i] : array[i] + 256;
}
```

Fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Java does not have unsigned bytes, so to convert them to ints as if they were unsigned, you need to AND them bitwise (`&`) with int `0xFF`:

```
byte[] array = new BigInteger("123456").toByteArray();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
    System.out.println(0xFF & array[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
1
226
64
```

You don't necessarily need to *store* them as an int array - it depends what you want to do with them...